# Why is this php function call failing?

Tags: php

I am attempting to use the following PHP class:

```
<?php 

class Service {

    public $code, $description;

    public static $services = array(
        "A"         =>      "Shipping",
        "B"     =>      "Manufacturing",
        "C"         =>      "Legal",
        "D"         =>      "Accounts Receivable",
        "E"         =>      "Human Resources",
        "F"         =>      "Security",
        "G"         =>      "Executive",
        "H"         =>      "IT"
    );

    public function _construct( $c, $d) {
        $this->code = $c;
        $this->description = $d;
    }

    public static function getDescription( $c ){
        return $services[$c];
    }

    public static function generateServiceList() {

        $service_list[] = array();

        foreach ($services as $k => $v ){
            $service_list[] = new Service( $k, $v );
        }

        return $service_list;

    }

}

?>
```

...in the following way:

```
<?php
    $services = Service::generateServiceList();
?>
```

...but getting the following error:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /classes/service.php on line 31
```

Any idea why? Is this some kind of an access issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$services` is undefined. Did yu mean `self::$services` ?

Comment: Nope - both the generateServiceList function and the array are static.

Answer (score 1):

`$services` variable is declared outside the function. When using classes, you have to access it by using `$this` keyword like that:

```
...
foreach ($this->services as $k => $v ){
...
```

Later edit: for static variables, use `self::$services` instead of `$this->services`.

Comment: Nope - both the generateServiceList function and the array are static.

Comment: Yes. If something is static, it is not tied to an object reference. That means that there is no $this-> services, rather a Service::$services array. The correct answer is the one by RiaD.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($services as $k => $v ){
            $service_list[] = new Service( $k, $v );
        }
```

to

```
foreach ($this->services as $k => $v ){
            $service_list[] = new Service( $k, $v );
        }
```

you want to refer to $services of the Class and not the local $services of the function.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it right now, but my gut feeling is to move `$service` is not being instantiated. I tend to use in this case a method for `init` variables. In this case you could create another method that would make

```
$services = array(
        "A"         =>      "Shipping",
        "B"     =>      "Manufacturing",
        "C"         =>      "Legal",
        "D"         =>      "Accounts Receivable",
        "E"         =>      "Human Resources",
        "F"         =>      "Security",
        "G"         =>      "Executive",
        "H"         =>      "IT"
```

Instantiation.